# Squash Lombok annotations

Tags: annotations, lombok

I have many classes with Lombok annotations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)
public class Employee extends AuditableEntity<Integer> {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;    
}
```

Is there any way to squash Getter, Setter, SuperBuilder, NoArgsConstructor, AllArgsConstructor, EqualsAndHashCode annotations to any one reusable component?

I tried to create custom annotation

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface Lombok {
}
```

but Lombok annotations are only supported on a class, enum or field type.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most frequently requested features for Lombok. Unfortunately, it's not easy to implement it. [There is some ongoing work](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/557), but it's only a proof-of-concept; there is no guarantee it will ever make it into Lombok.